# I challenge you to find a reasonable-ish use case for `del` before function return

Tags: python, garbage-collection, del

I'm currently working with a legacy system that has been developed by half a dozen people before me, each fixing issues and adding new features without bothering with anything silly like "code reviews", "documentation" or "style guides". The people before me have also had very varying levels of coding expertise, and so the resulting codebase could be described as "colourful" for the lack of a better term.

Thus the codebase is filled with normal code, clever bits, brilliant hacks and horrible spaghetti scripts. It is not always obvious which is which. One of my favourite puzzles in the code looks functionally like this:

```py
def main_function(text, number):
    check_flag, squared_number = auxiliary_function(number)
    if check_flag == False:
        error = "Number could not be squared."
        return False, error

    combined_data = text + str(squared_number)

    del check_flag
    return True, combined_data


def auxiliary_function(number):
    try:
        result = number * number
        return True, result
    except Exception as e:
        return False, number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "Hello, world! "
    number = 42
    check_flag, result = main_function(text, number)
    print(result)

    text = "Hello, world! "
    number = "42"
    check_flag, result = main_function(text, number)
    print(result)
```

Now, there is a lot going on even in this small snippet, much of it not very Pythonic, but what I really want to focus on is the `del check_flag` part just before the `main_function` returns. Why do I call this *a puzzle* instead of *clearly superfluous code*? The reason is that so far from basically every piece of weird code in this project I've been able to learn something by either figuring out what kind of edge case could make a given approach theoretically feasible, or by studying enough Python machinery to see why a given piece of code could never work as intended.

But here I am a bit bogged down due to my lacking understanding of the `del` command, function scope fundamentals and Python garbage collection. (In the past few years I think I've had one occasion where I had a reasonable case of using `del`, though probably I could have avoided even that by using the Pandas library more fluently.)

Having played around with how function scopes work with `del`, it seems that the only case where `del`ing *anything* (primitives or objects) inside a function scope is if the thing to be deleted has been forced to have a wider scope e.g. with `global`. So in theory this could be used in a case where I want to have a global flag variable that enables me to use tertiary logic with the values of `True`, `False` and `NameError`. (Far-fetched and horrible, I know.)

I know that sometimes bad code is just bad code, but still I would like to ask if anyone could figure any complex settings e.g. in complex object inheritance, async functions or something else where "`del` just before function return" might actually be even a borderline reasonable thing to do? Or, alternatively, is there something fundamental about function scopes that rules out anything else than deleting objects in larger scopes?

Comment: That looks like just a piece of nonsense code in a stink of bad code smells. `check_flag` is just a boolean var, there is no way that `del` on it does anything useful

Comment: Simply git blame that line and read the commit message / PR / issue :-). What do you mean with "primitives"?

Comment: Local variables are lost when the stack frame is deleted at function exit. So this code line has no value; maybe an artifact from some now-forgotten intention or just misguided.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm hoping for too much trying to find pearls in this code ^^

@KellyBundy I was referring to the fact that we are deleting here a Boolean which in my mind fits in to the set of primitives like int, float and str which might behave differently than more complex objects like functions or Objects. (Though I guess in Python the differences are not that big.)

Comment: bools, ints, floats and strs are all objects, though. "primitives or objects" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @KellyBundy ah, you're right. I can almost bring myself to remember&believe that, but somehow I'm still always a bit hesitant if they're *really* going to be handled in the same way ^^ This is probably a weird instinct left over from Java/C or something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even have a good "bad" reason for doing that on a boolean.  Given the history of that code however, it could be a remnant of some experimentation that wasn't properly cleaned up.  For example, if the code was doing something with `locals()` afterwards (it's not but perhaps in an earlier incarnation), there could be some far fetched logic to determine which local variables were assigned during the process and this would exclude that flag from locals() before using it.